# sweetalert2: Add a second alert without removing the first one

Tags: sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) to show a table with some data and some buttons, so far it's been working great, but when the user clics on the button I would like to open a new alert with an input. the problem, is that when I call the sweetalert function again, the previous alert with the table gets replaced with the new one.

is it posible to have 2 alerts at the same time, or at least, go back to the previous one?

Comment: It is not possible to have 2 alerts at the same time. Do you have some code that you have tried because you could possibly "go back" by recreating the old one.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's the queue functionality in SweetAlert2:

```js
swal.queue([
  // Step 0
  {
    title: 'The next modal will have an input field',
    confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;'
  },
  
  // Step 1
  {
    title: 'Enter your email address',
    input: 'email'
  }
]).then(result => {
  console.log(
    result.value[1] // read value of the 1st step
  )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7"></script>
```

Docs: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#chaining-modals

Comment: yes I saw that, but what I need is the first modal not to dissapear.

Answer (score 1):

Queue with a "Back" Button example: https://sweetalert2.github.io/recipe-gallery/queue-with-back-button.html

```js
async function runSteps() {
    const steps = ['1', '2', '3']
    const swalQueueStep = Swal.mixin({
        confirmButtonText: 'Forward',
        cancelButtonText: 'Back',
        progressSteps: steps,
        input: 'text',
        inputAttributes: {
            required: true
        },
        reverseButtons: true,
        validationMessage: 'This field is required'
    })

    const values = []
    let currentStep

    for (currentStep = 0; currentStep < steps.length;) {
        const result = await swalQueueStep.fire({
            title: `Question ${steps[currentStep]}`,
            inputValue: values[currentStep],
            showCancelButton: currentStep > 0,
            currentProgressStep: currentStep
        })

        if (result.value) {
            values[currentStep] = result.value
            currentStep++
        } else if (result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel) {
            currentStep--
        } else {
            break
        }
    }

    if (currentStep === steps.length) {
        Swal.fire(JSON.stringify(values))
    }
}

runSteps()
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```